# Move Player Sequentially on an Array Path in Unity Board Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have Transform[] array I want to move Player one by one on every point on array
.Right now I am using Vector3.MoveTowards according to Dice Value but its moving directly to new Position according to Dice

```
    void FixedUpdate () 
{

    if (currentpoint<points1.Length) {
        Player.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (Player.transform.position, points1 [currentpoint].position,Time.deltaTime * 2f);

            }
}
```

And for Increment the integer variable currentpoint I am Using

```
    public void movePlayer ()
{   

   currentpoint += DIceValue;

}
```

I have a circular path So its moving directly to new Path according to diceValue.

Comment: I have posted the code . thanks for responding

Comment: So for example if you have 6 on the dice you would like it to move to 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on up to 6th position on the boar but it move to 6th directly?

Comment: yes it moves directly to 6

Comment: What you have to do is to iterate through positions. Now you just move to the last position, but what you should have is:
If you have 6 on the dice you move 6 times to the next position in the positions array. You have to change currentpoint++ after end of the every step (you can do it by comparing Player.transform.position to points1[currentpoint].position)

Comment: Also It could be easier if you use iTween library from Asset Store. Helps making paths and other transitions.

Comment: Thanks I have done it using iTween.putOnpath